# Bookmarks missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ribbon

I am following this URL http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=40
in  my O365 environment.  But in my environment **Bookmark** tab is missing. It is only showing the following: [image]

can any one tell why is it coming like this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabled SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature on the site collection level and then the SharePoint Server Publishing feature must be activated on the site level